# Non-Cached Data Being Served as Cached Data in Front Door

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, cache-control, azure-cdn, azure-front-door

I have a Front Door / CDN with caching enabled that uses the response from an API Management service to determine what specific content to cache.

The API Management service has a set of endpoints, the majority of which are set to cache-control: no-cache with a few set to cache-control: s-maxage: [length].

When deploying these caching changes to API Management and then enabling the cache on Front Door / CDN I observed a behaviour in Front Door that it responded with cached data for data I have explicitly set to cache-control: no-cache. This continued for a short duration until I: Purged Front Door, Disabled Front Door Caching, and then rolled back the policy change in API Management.

What I understand that happened in this instance was that if the Front Door changes had been made first or the changes to API Management failed for whatever reason then Front Door caches everything.

However, when I re-attempted this change again, making sure the API Management changes were completed first; I still observed the same behaviour - observing (what I explicitly set as non-cached data) being returned by the cache.

[image: Network Diagram]

Are there any known issues with regards to the propagation of deploying changes to API Management and suitable mitigations, i.e. the changes need to reach all instances, to avoid this occurring?